# Cpp file can find libary header file but header file can't using Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

FYI Im very new with cmake.

I have the following Structure in my project:

```
main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
writer_pool/
- writer_pool.cpp
- writer_pool.h
- CMakeLists.txt
```

Both writer_pool.cpp and writer_pool.h have #include "json/json.h" from the JsonCpp package (https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp).  Except the issue is that the include statement only works in the writer_pool.cpp file and not writer_pool.h (gives json/json.h: No such file or directory).  I.e. if I remove #include "json/json.h" from writer_pool.h the project compiles fine.

My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.18)

project(pipeline)

add_subdirectory(writer_pool)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

find_package(jsoncpp REQUIRED)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PUBLIC
        writer_pool

        )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PUBLIC
        writer_pool
        )

target_link_libraries(objects ${JSON_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(objects PUBLIC ${JSON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_options(objects PUBLIC ${JSON_CFLAGS_OTHER})
```

and my writer_pool/CMakeLists.txt is:

```
add_library(objects objects.cpp)
```

I am completely stuck on how to get #include "json/json.h" in writer_pool.h and to actually compile...any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Figure out what `JSON_INCLUDE_DIRS` is (you can print it from within cmakelists.txt), then it all should fall in place.

Comment: You are linking the missing target `writer_pool` against the missing target `pipeline`. Something seems weird... which target includes writer_pool.h and causes the compile error?

Comment: Please, make sure that you question contains a code which *can* be built. Also add to the question post the exact error message you get. See also [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: There are no such variables as `JSON_LIBRARIES`, `JSON_INCLUDE_DIRS` or `JSON_CFLAGS_OTHER` in `jsoncppConfig.cmake` (the file which should be discovered & consumed by `find_package(jsoncpp REQUIRED)`). You should link to `JsonCpp::JsonCpp` imported target.

Comment: @local-ninja apologies, the actual cmake is much larger, I've reduced it for this post and accidentally took out the target. I've added it in.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes JSON_INCLUDE_DIRS and JSON_CFLAGS_OTHER exist.  I do can a message(${JSON_LIBRARIES}) or message(${JSON_INCLUDE_DIRS}) and it prints.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. could you explain what you mean?  Like sure I could adjust the path ""json/json.h" in write_pool.h to whatever is in JSON_INCLUDE_DIRS...but if there is another include statement inside ""json/json.h" then it will fail.

Comment: Hmm I must have misread your question. You are describing a quite impossible situation. Please post a [mcve] (you can remove all the code except relevant `#include` directives).